# named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments gave been specified

Tags: c#, lambda

I have problems with this line of my code:

```
return View(unitOfWork.roleRepository.Get(s => s.OrderBy(z => z.Id), Page: 15, p => p.Id == 1, u => u.RoleName != "null"));
```

this line throws an exception with this message:

> named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments gave been specified

And here is the method declaration:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        int? Page=0,
        params Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>[] filter)
```

How can I modify my argument list to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to simply not provide the name of the page argument:

```
return View(unitOfWork.roleRepository.Get(s => s.OrderBy(z => z.Id), 15, p => p.Id == 1, u => u.RoleName != "null"));
```